# Stuck with JavaFX ListView

Tags: java, swing, listview, javafx, factory

I'm trying to rewrite my Android based app into JavaFX and stuck with one problem.

Brief explanation of problem looks like following:

1) I have hierarchy of classes with root `abstract class Field` and number of child classes like `FieldCat`, `FieldZebra`, `FieldDog` and so on - each of these classes has its own unique enough structure and visual representation (in form of FXML's)

2) There's `ListView` which should show list of objects which belongs to `Field` hierarchy - stored in `ObservableList<Field> listItems`

3) And now I need to inflate each of my `FieldWhatever` objects as separate row in `ListView`

**Statement**

I can't do it with JavaFX `ListView` control(?!)

**Proof**

The only way to create `ListView` element is to supply `CellFactory`:

```
public class FieldsListCellFactory<T extends Field> implements Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>> {

    @Override
    public ListCell<T> call(ListView<T> listView) {
         //blah-blah
    }
}
```

Factory receives single parameter `ListView` itself, so it can generate the same `ListCell` for all elements of `ListView` - in other words I can't populate different UI elements depending on underlying `FieldWhatever` object.

For the very beginning I couldn't even believe to it - how it's possible? In Android I could inflate any kind of complexity UI's depending on object type/hierarchy and so on, but in JavaFX - impossible? Believe me - I spent hours trying to fix it - useless.

**Questions**

1. Am I right (I would really pleasured to hear that I'm wrong)
2. What do to? How to resolve situation and put/place/inflate in
   List/Table list of totally different objects/classes/entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad 1 You are wrong.

Ad 2 Here's the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ListView<Animal> listview = new ListView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Dog(1, "John"), new Cat(2, "Fluffy")));
        listview.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<Animal>() {

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Animal animal, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(animal, empty);
                if (animal != null) {
                    setText(animal.getText());
                }
            }
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(listview));
        stage.show();
    }
}

class Animal {
    protected final int id;

    public Animal(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    protected String getText() {
        return "";
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    private final String owner;

    public Dog(int id, String owner) {
        super(id);
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getText() {
        return "DOG id=" + id + ", owner=" + owner;
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    private final String name;

    public Cat(int id, String name) {
        super(id);
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getText() {
        return "CAT id=" + id + ", name=" + name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was expecting to have `ListCell<Cat/Dog>` rather than ListCell<Animal>`...  - I was planning to load fxml's in respective constructors not in `updateItem()` - do you have solution?

Comment: I really can't get it how it is supposed to work? You were writing about Android code  in which you are able to implement your desired structure, can you give me any link to Android code example?

Comment: @barmaley If I understand what you're saying that won't work. In JavaFX, virtualized controls like `ListView` and `TableView` **reuse** cell instances while scrolling. So doing what you'd want your `ListCell<Dog>` could suddenly have a `Cat` as its item; same with `ListCell<Cat>` and `Dog`.

Comment: @PrzemekKrysztofiak for instance [look here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Implementing-a-Heterogenous-ListView)

Comment: @Slaw what about 2nd part of my question?

Comment: @barmaley Ok, now I get it. My question is - why do you want to use Android framework solution in JavaFx, what are the features provided by Android solution which you cannot achive with JavaFx? I really don't get the phrase with loading fxml's in constructors, not updateItems(). You play by the rules of  the framework you are using, not the rules of other framework.
To sum up - I really cannot see the problem. Please provide me feature description you cannot achive with JavaFx which was implemented in Android.

Comment: @PrzemekKrysztofiak I understand your point. I tried your approach - and it's working, thanks for hint!